# subsitute a column value with meaningful data and display in mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, select

I want to retreive values from my table "A" that will check the value of 'status' column and print meaningful information instead of number.

For example,

if status is 0 then display 'Active' instead of 0

if status is 1 then display 'Inactive' instead of 1

if status is 2 then display 'Suspended' instead of 2

Current result:

```
Number     Value     Status
--------   ------    -------
000001     1000      0
000001     1001      1
000001     1002      2
```

Expected result:

```
Number     Value     Status
--------   ------    -------
000001     1000      Active
000001     1001      Inactive
000001     1002      Suspended
```

I am new to this field and I did some initial research, but couldn't find answers. Any help regarding the matter would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `case` statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) as follows:

```
select Number, Value, 
  case 
    when Status = 0 then 'Active' 
    when Status = 1 then 'Inactive' 
    when Status = 2 then 'Suspended' 
  end as Status 
from A;
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't no how to write the above code in Codeigniter. Can I get any help?

Comment: @gecco, its hard to figure out where to start.  Have a look at this tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if($row['status'] == 0) $status_string = 'Active';
  if($row['status'] == 1) $status_string = 'Inactive';
  if($row['status'] == 2) $status_string = 'Suspended';
  echo $row['number'].', '.$row['value'].', '.$status_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the table schema, consider casting the column as type [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
    `Number` INT(6) ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Value` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Same` ENUM('Active', 'Inactive', 'Suspended') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Inactive'
);
```

Now you can set the value by its literal rather than trying to convert in your application layer. ENUM does not consume memory/disk like a VARCHAR/CHAR column, so no worries there.

Comment: No I have no access to change the existing table. :(